# How to check if managed metadata has a keyword in CAML query?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, caml-query, caml

I want to make a caml query that checks if a managed metadata column (which is a list of phrases) contains a certain phrase. I have this which seems to work, but the problem is it does a substring check, so if there was a keyword called `ModeBook`, then that item would be included, but I want the ones that contain the exact phrase `Mode`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

```
<Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name="MMtype" />
                <Value Type="Text">Mode</Value>
            </Contains>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to switch to LinQ, or some client side script to pull out substrings. I am not aware of a way to do what you are asking.